# How do I make a search filter that includes unread messages OR flagged messages?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2013

I can make a search filter based on unread AND flagged messages. But what I need is unread OR Flagged messages. To make a sort of "pay attention to these items" search folder.

When I try to use the advanced search tool, unread is no longer an option that I can find. Maybe I am blind.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom folder view and specify a filter criteria manually on the **SQL** tab like this:

```
("urn:schemas:httpmail:read" = 0 OR NOT("urn:schemas:httpmail:messageflag" IS NULL))
```

Unfortunately, Outlook UI doesn't allow you to specify this kind of criteria for a search folder =( It can only be done programmatically using MAPI.

Comment: Thank you. It seems a shame that you can't filter on unread in the other filters.

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but I `Edit`'ed one of the Smart Folders in Outlook '16 (Mac OS X) to filter on these two clauses:

1. Folder is Inbox
2. 'Raw Query': `com_microsoft_outlook_unread == 1 || com_microsoft_outlook_flagged == 1`